# Обработка клика по элементу в ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `ListView`, в котором отображаются папки. Мне нужно, чтобы по клику на элементе, в другом `ListView` отображались список файлов в папке на которую я щелкнул, как мне обработать событие при клике?

Comment: `WPF` или `WinForms`?

Comment: WPF............

Comment: `MVVM` используете? Если нет - почему? Если да - привязывайте `SelectedItem` первого `ListView` в `VM` и в сеттере меняйте коллекцию привязанную ко второму `ListView`

Comment: не пользуюсь подскажите какую лучше использовать и где её скачать ?

Comment: `MVVM` - это подход (паттерн/шаблон) к проектированию приложения с разделением его на независимые части. Обязательно к изучению, если хотите создавать чуть более сложные приложения `WPF`.

Comment: Привязку (`Binding`) хотя бы используете?

Comment: тоже нет я чайник конкретный... (

Comment: подскажите может статью хорошую для работы с mvvm ?

Comment: [1](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/base_WPF/level1/info_WPF.php), [2](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/)

Comment: Зачем человека грузить разными паттернами, фреймфорками и прочими вещами? Это только еще больше внесет сумбур и непонимание "чего и как". Нужна база, не нее нужно делать акцент. Если она будет все остальное со временем придет.

Comment: @sp7, поэтому я и даю ссылки на изучение WPF вообще. Для начала надо понять `Binding` и прочее, а потом уже пробовать `MVVM`

Comment: @Андрей я думаю здесь до WPF далеко еще. Собственно тут посыл даже больше к автору вопроса. Нужна база, без нее никуда.

Comment: @FoggyFinder сам язык, основные классы, те самые рабочие лошадки, с которыми приходится в большинстве случае иметь дело.

Comment: @FoggyFinder потому что я уже помогал этому автору и понял это из его вопросов. Не хочу, конечно, никого обидеть, это просто дружеский совет )

Comment: Я сразу написал что чайник ) учусь пробую тренируюсь )